# Using live ads while beta testing with admob ads

Tags: android, android-studio, ads

I have just published my android app to beta. When developing the app I had the code set to set the ads to testing, but when I changed the code to what google says for development the ads do not show up. Is this just because there are no live ads in beta, or is my code not showing the ad. Here is my code...

MainActivity

```
AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

XML...

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    app:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

AndroidManifest

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any issue with your code. everything seems to be correct. The issue maybe with `ads:adUnitId` that you are using. Try creating new `ads:adUnitId` and check.See details about AdMob here http://www.google.com/ads/admob/

Hope it helps.

Comment: So your saying this code should pop up the ad during beta testing

Comment: If you have given `com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0` as dependency in `build.gradle` then it should work fine. try `addTestDevice` property to confirm in your beta testing. Also see here about banner size https://developers.google.com/admob/android/banner?hl=en

Comment: That could be the problem I had 8.3.0